# How can I combine two attributes form a table to make one "event"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry if I'm asking this question wrong.

In rails I need to find events and display the attributes in my view. The unique identifiers from the `event` table is `sid` and `cid`. The `sid` identifies an ips sensor, and the `cid` is an event id from a specific ips sensor. If I use `@event = IpsEvent.find 2` it pulls the first row that starts with `sid` 2.

Below is an example from the `event` table in my db;

```
SELECT * from event;
 sid | cid | signature |         timestamp          
-----+-----+-----------+----------------------------
   1 |   1 |         1 | 2014-05-22 20:50:07.154-04
   1 |   2 |         1 | 2014-05-22 20:50:28.123-04
   2 |   1 |         1 | 2014-05-22 23:14:38.912-04
   2 |   2 |         1 | 2014-05-22 23:14:38.912-04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make more than one column as a primary key please use the composite primary keys libs, just look at this http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/. Still you need help please let me know.

Comment: I think this may be what I need. I'll look at it and see if it's what I'm looking for. Thanks!